# How Can You Lock Rows of Cells in Excel Based on Cell Value?

Tags: excel, vba

So I know that one can format cells to be locked and then protect a worksheet to prevent that data being overwritten. But I'm looking to be able to dynamically lock cells within a sheet. From doing some Googling I've tried adapting the below block of code for my needs. The intent is that if column A has a value the rest of the row will be locked so no one can overwrite the rest of the row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(ActiveSheet.Cells(18, 1), Target) Is Not Nothing Then
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(18, 1).Text = "X" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(18, 2), Cells(18, 20)).Locked = True
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(18, 2), Cells(18, 20)).Locked = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as well as tips for succinctly applying this to every row in the sheet.

UPDATE:

Per BigBen's answer I've revised to the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets(“Sheet8”).Protect Password:="Secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Me.Columns(1), Target)

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        cell.EntireRow.Locked = (cell.Value = "X")
    Next
End Sub
```

But that still doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: `IsNot Nothing` =) It looks like you're confused with vb.net

Comment: `that still doesn't seem to be working.` - what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `Intersect` to test if `Target` intersects column A, and not a particular cell:

Note also the `Not` syntax: `If Not Intersect... Is Nothing`, instead of `If Intersect... Is Not Nothing`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Me.Columns(1), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Dim rng as Range
        For Each rng in Intersect(Me.Columns(1), Target)
            If rng.Value = "X" Then
                rng.EntireRow.Locked = True
            Else
                rng.EntireRow.Locked = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Or perhaps a bit more succinctly:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Me.Columns(1), Target)

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        cell.EntireRow.Locked = (cell.Value = "X")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Using either of those blocks of code I get "Runtime error '1004': Unable to set the Locked property of the Range class" any time I make changes to a cell in column A. Whether I start with all cells locked or unlocked I get this error when attempting to edit the protected sheet.

Comment: Right - because you can't edit a protected sheet unless you unprotect first, or protect with `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused then. If the sheet is unprotected then doesn't locking cells still allow users to alter them? The intent is for no one to be able to overwrite information once the X is entered. Would we also have to protect/unprotect the sheet when making changes?

Comment: Yes... unless you originally protect the sheet programmatically using `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`.

Comment: I revised the question per your comments to show what I'm running now. I'm still not getting the expected results, the user interface only code block doesn't appear to be doing anything?

Comment: Where do you have the `Workbook_Open` code? Should be in the `ThisWorkbook` module - also fix the quotes around `"Sheet8"`.

Comment: I'm assuming you want the cell in column A to remain unlocked though? In that case I'd have to revised the use of `EntireRow`.

Comment: Yes, that did it! Thank you so much for the troubleshooting. Locking column A should be fine but I'll look into what methods there are besides `EntireRow` in case it's an issue. Thanks again!

Comment: You could use `Offset` and `Resize`... `cell.Offset(,1).Resize(,Me.Columns.Count - 1).Locked`